# Second-order differential equation with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I try to solve using laplace transform
$y'' + y = \sin (t)$ with $y(0) = 1$ and $y'(0) = 2$
but I don't get a solution, I don't know why. I check my work and it seems fine.

[My calculations](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KSRzwrPp2QzjYD0MvAzbP_aucUqYIpiI)

Is possible the initial conditions are wrong, or not consistent with the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the transform we have

$$
s^2Y(s)+Y(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+1}+s \dot y(0) + y(0)
$$

or

$$
Y(s) = \frac{1}{(s^2+1)^2}+\frac{s}{s^2+1}\dot y(0)+\frac{1}{s^2+1}y(0)
$$

At this point we can use the Laplace transforms table assigning the due inverses

$$
y(t) = \left(\frac{1}{2}(\sin(t)-t\cos(t))+\cos(t)\dot y(0)+\sin(t)y(0)\right)u(t)
$$

where $u(t)$ is the unit step function.

Comment: You are correct, i transform badly $y$. but why you multiply for $u(t)$  $cos(t) y\prime(0) + sin(t) y(0)$

Comment: The Laplace transform in this case, is null for $t \lt 0$ This is performed by the multiplication of $u(t)$

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistakes for B and C

$$B=\frac 1 {s+1} \quad ;C=\frac 3 {s(s+1]}$$

You already had some mistakes before that step...
It should be

$$F(s)=\frac s {(s^2+1)}+\frac 1 {(s^2+1)^2}+\frac 2 {s^2+1}$$ 
You applied the laplace transform on
$$y''+y'=\sin(t)$$
And not on
$$y''+y=\sin(t)$$